# wordpress passing parameter to custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using wordpress.
I have created a page dealer-profile from admin and assigned  a template to it. Now I want to pass a parameter like

```
SITE-URL/dealer-profile/SUV
```

I have added following into my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^dealer-profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?pagename=dealer-profile&dealer=$1 [QSA]
```

I have also tried following

```
add_rewrite_rule('dealer-profile/([^/]+)', 'index.php?pagename=dealer- profile&dealer=$matches[1]', 'top');
flush_rewrite_rules(false);
```

when I am requesting `SITE-URL/dealer-profile/SUV`, it automatically redirects to `SITE-URL/dealer-profile`

Please suggest, where I am wrong.

Now I am doing following

```
function themeslug_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'dealer';
  return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('dealer-profile/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=dealer-profile&dealer=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

But this is working for digits only like 
- test/dealer-profile/234234/ is working 
- test/dealer-profile/234234/ is not working

**Solution**

Ref : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );
// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset( $rules['(dealer-profile)/(.*)$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['dealer-profile/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=dealer-profile&dealer=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'dealer');
    return $vars;
}
```

Thanks A lot for Your Help @@jnhghy - Jantea Alexandri

Comment: there is a typo on the last line, the 2 urls (working url and not working url) are the same: test/dealer-profile/234234/ is working - test/dealer-profile/234234/ can you please corect that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a function to add query variables to query string and then hook that function into the query_vars hook:

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
$aVars[] = "dealer-profile"; // represents the name of the variable that you want to pass
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

then we need to add the rewrite rule:
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('dealer-profile/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=dealer-profile=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}

// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Getting the variable:

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['dealer-profile'])) {
$sMsdsCat = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['dealer-profile']);
}
```

and this should do the trick,
and here are some extra link for "advanced rules":
http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/
http://www.prodeveloper.org/create-your-own-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress.html

EDIT: let us try the steps that we have in the second article:
First let's create the tag and add it to the rewrite rules (this should work for alpha-numeric values:

```
function createRewriteRules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // add rewrite tokens
    $dealertag = '%dealertag%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag($dealertag, '(.+?)', 'dealer-profile=');

    $keywords_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . "dealer-profile/$dealertag/";
    $keywords_rewrite = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($keywords_structure);

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $keywords_rewrite + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'createRewriteRules');
```

Then hook generate rules like this:

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
        add_rewrite_rule('^dealer-profile/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&dealer-profile=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

add the variable to query vars:

```
function query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = "dealer-profile";
    return $public_query_vars;
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

bonus:
To debug your rules you can use this function:

```
function dev4press_debug_rewrite_rules() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  echo '<div>';
  if (!empty($wp_rewrite->rules)) {
    echo '<h5>Rewrite Rules</h5>';
    echo '<table><thead><tr>';
    echo '<td>Rule</td><td>Rewrite</td>';
    echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    foreach ($wp_rewrite->rules as $name => $value) {
      echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
  } else {
    echo 'No rules defined.';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

it's from https://docs.dev4press.com/tutorial/wordpress/debug-wordpress-rewrite-rules-matching/ and it should show you all your rules in a table format, just include it in any of your templates and check if the above functions are adding the rewrite rules correctly if not, it should give you some extra info about what didn't worked.

And you can also use the well known [Developer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developer/screenshots/) plugin to inspect your rules, you'll get extra info with this plugin!!!

Comment: thanks for the reply though this is not working.
http://Siteurl/?pagename=dealer-profile
Even this is not working after appling this rule. Normally it is working directly.

Comment: `function themeslug_query_vars( $qvars ) {




        $qvars[] = 'dealer';

        return $qvars;

    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
    function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
 $aNewRules = array('dealer-profile/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php? pagename=dealer-profile&dealer=$matches[1]');
     $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
     return $aRules;
    }

    add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');`

Comment: But this is working only for the digits
like local/dealer-profile/345345345/ and not local/dealer-profile/asdasd/

Comment: @user2932242: please check the answer again (you might start with the developer plugin and inspect your already created rules, if you can't debug then you can start working on the solution) hope it works out!

Comment: thanks a lot. These troubleshooting help me alot. Now I am getting list of all rules. But no new rule is  added to this list I tried in .htaccess also . Fulsh rewrite rules also.

I have created a page with name dealer page it has slug dealer-page
and assigned a template to it. Now I am trying to add rewrite rules but noting working.

Comment: @user2932242: is the .htaccess file wirteble? check its permissions!

Comment: I checked this. Now I am flushing the rewrite rule on plugin activation hook. This show rewrite rule for once and then disappear when I reload the page.

Comment: Do you have any cache plugins? other security plugins? that would not let your .htaccess get highjacked? any security scripts with same scope that will rebuild the .htaccess file?

Comment: Thanks A lot for Your Help @@jnhghy - Jantea Alexandri
I have posted solution that worked for me. :)